# Flip a switch using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two switches:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="switch1" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="switch1">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="switch2" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="switch2">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

I would like their states to always be the opposite of the other... If switch1 is in the ON position, switch2 automatically turns to the OFF position, and vice versa.

How can I do this using javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: please include in your question the plugin (name) / script you're using to construct the switch (click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27417801/edit) to modify your post)...

Answer (score 0):

If you want one and only one to be enabled, change checkbox to radio.

If you want zero or only one, you need to track the onchange for each one and change the other accordingly.

Example for Zero or only one:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="switch1" onchange="switch1hecked()" >
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="switch1">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="switch2" onchange="switch2hecked()"  >
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="switch2">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>

<script>
    function switch1hecked() {
        if (document.getElementById('switch1').checked)
            document.getElementById('switch2').checked = false;
    }

    function switch2hecked() {
        if (document.getElementById('switch2').checked)
            document.getElementById('switch1').checked = false;
    }
</script>
```